# python-bitcoinlib | Create Private Keys, Public Keys and Addresses - How to Do It?

Tags: private-key, public-key, address-generation, python, python-bitcoinlib

I'm trying to use the [python-bitcoinlib](https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib/) library but its docs aren't entirely clear to me.
I'm a programmer but quite new to Python, and not very versed in the Bitcoin protocol.

What's the process, code-wise, with the library, for the following?

1. Generating a private key
2. Creating a public key
3. Creating an address from the public key

I tried various things and am not completely sure what arguments I supply to what functions, and what functions I'm supposed to use in the process.

I'd appreciate a lot, and I think it'd help me the most if I were provided code for achieving each step.

I was able to follow the Bitcoin protocol (specifically, the [developer reference](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference) and the [developer guide](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide) on [bitcoin.org](http://bitcoin.org) to do all of those things, and I'm looking specifically how to do it with the library, so I could have my code fully compatible with other functionality of it, since I'd like to use the library for additional purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry I am not familiar with python-bitcoinlib but if your goal is to just create keys/addresses you can use [this](https://github.com/mcdallas/cryptotools) library (disclosure: I wrote it) the following way:

> Generating a private key

`private = PrivateKey.random()`

or `private = PrivateKey.from_hex('yourhexkeyhere')`

or `private = PrivateKey.from_wif('yourwifhere')`

and then to get the hex representation use `private.hex()` of `private.wif()`

> Creating a public key

```
public = private.to_public()
public.hex()
'044cc549c65f4b0b7713d7a763a01221f85fd34602ac8ff0386995349c55de7111d16b5...'
public.hex(compressed=True)
'034cc549c65f4b0b7713d7a763a01221f85fd34602ac8ff0386995349c55de7111'
```

> Creating an address from the public key

```
public.to_address('P2PKH')
'16B2Ghyu5C1CofKfXF2Zi9JycqaAyaE8cd'
public.to_address('P2WPKH')
'bc1qtqshpjw8kr7jlk27gcvj7pvzt8lp6vn5dc2f24'
```

If you use this library please use it only as a learning tool and not to send real coins as there might still be some bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Some usage examples are now available in the repository.

- [This example](https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib/blob/master/examples/spend-p2wpkh.py) demonstrates how to generate a key pair, and create a transaction paying to the public key hash (P2WPKH).
  There is also [the legacy version](https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib/blob/master/examples/spend-p2pkh-txout.py) (P2PKH).
- [This example](https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib/blob/master/examples/spend-p2wsh-txout.py) demonstrates how to use more complex Bitcoin Script with P2WSH.
  There is also [the legacy version](https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib/blob/master/examples/spend-p2sh-txout.py) (P2SH).